# Django display a view in every page

Tags: python, django, templates, for-loop, django-context

I want to run my for loop in every page. I have same of the code below in my views.py.

```
def hepsi(request):
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')
    return render_to_response("base.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and this is my urls.py part:

```
url(r'^$', 'hepsi', name = "hepsiliste"),
```

I have a for loop in base.html:

```
{% for baslik in basliklar %}
     <div>
         <a href="{% url "tek_baslik" baslik.slug %}"><h2> {{ baslik }} </h2></a>
         <p><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ baslik.user }}</p>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

it works in home page but it does not work in other pages like as /baslik/x

How can I make this work in every page user wants?

Comment: Look for *context processor* how to include template data for every template: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a context processor

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

so that each template will found `baslikar` variable in the context.

However it is not clear how your `hepsi` function works, since the variable baslikar is never used... Maybe it is computed in `locals()`?